# Apache Server: IP Address Routes to Domain Instead of DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost, httpd, ip-address

I have only one website in my server. My desire is to open different directory when the IP address is used as the URL in web browser. However, even though I set the DocumentRoot to a different directory, IP address is opening my domain.com instead.

If I remove the .conf file of that domain.com, then IP address is opening the DocumentRoot as expected.

Here is my configuration:

**conf.d/domain.com.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domaincom
        ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        <Directory "/var/www/html/domaincom">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**conf/httpd.conf file**

```
ServerTokens OS
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 60
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
Listen 80
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
# ...
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
UseCanonicalName Off
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir disabled
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
DefaultType text/plain
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog logs/error_log
LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
# ...
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
ServerSignature On
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"

<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Location of the WebDAV lock database.
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip

AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
# ...
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*

AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
# ...
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
AddLanguage ca .ca
# ...
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw
LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR ru sv zh-CN zh-TW
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType application/x-compress .Z
# ...
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
AddHandler type-map var
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml

Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
# ...
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully

NameVirtualHost *:80
Include conf.d/*.conf
```

What could be possibly wrong with this configuration? Or if that's a default behaviour, how can I work it as I declared?

Comment: Are there any other .conf files in conf.d ?

Comment: @lain, Default files: @, README, notrace.conf, perl.conf, php.conf, ssl.conf, welcome.conf, wsgi.conf

Comment: So if you disable them and restart httpd what happens ?

Comment: @lain Same, both IP address and domain are opening the domain root.

Comment: Sorry I appear to have misread the question, the first defined vhost will be the default vhost so it gets served if nothing else matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are defining `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your `httpd.conf` the only VirtualHost definition you have is being used when connecting via the IP.

Put the following into `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (at the end) or in a new file called `/etc/httpd/conf.d/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName servername.host.com
  ServerAlias *.servername.host.com
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart Apache and see if that corrects it.

The important thing to keep in mind is the VirtualHost definition  you want to be the default has to be defined before any other VirtualHost definitions.